# Port forwarding with xinetd

Tags: linux, networking, centos, portforwarding, xinetd

I want to forward xinetd connection to another local port (say 12345). I based my solution  on CentOS/Redhat documentation Chapter 17. [TCP Wrappers and xinetd, article 17.4.3.3](http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/rhel-rg-en-4/s1-tcpwrappers-xinetd-config.html). In the example the configuration starts a daemon and also redirects the traffic to a host:port. The doco say it should be able to forward to different port on the same system too.

My current goal is to  starts a daemon (say testsmpp) at any connection on port 12345 and redirect the stream to a particular port (say 54321). The tricky bit is I don't want the daemon (testsmpp) to read from STDIN, instead it should be able to read from the port where the xinetd is forwarding the traffic to.

I created a service under /etc/service e.g

```
testsmpp    12345/tcp
```

And my xinetd configuration for the daemon is

```
service testsmpp
{
    sock_type =     stream
    protocol =      tcp
    wait =          no
    user =          root
    server =        /home/me/bin/testsmpp        
    redirect =      54321
}
```

testsmpp listens on port 54321. The problem is when a connection made from outside, xinetd starts the daemon but do not forward the traffic to 54321. Once the server started I can connect directly to 54321 port but the connection made via xinetd (at port 12345) is not forwarded.

Is server and redirect tags are mutually exclusive? I looked at the discussion about [xinet forking concurrent server](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/207412/seeking-xinetd-alternative-for-forking-concurrent-servers-in-linux?newreg=c19184b05fc54d948d7417eaf984a782) but my motivation are slightly different. I want to listen for incoming connection on another port as the other application will communicate with the daemon on that port too in a distributed computing environment.

Any clues much appreciated.

Comment: It would be nice how you get the answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691913/program-running-and-redirected-with-xinetd-in-different-ports-for-centos

Answer (score 4):

This is a sample config, [obtained from this source](http://www.centosblog.com/port-forwarding-using-xinetd-on-centos/), and it worked for me:

```
service smtp_forward
{
    disable         = no
    type            = UNLISTED
    socket_type     = stream
    protocol        = tcp
    user            = nobody
    wait            = no
    redirect        = remote_server 25
    port            = 2000
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use both ip and port in the redirect.  Something like

```
redirect = 127.0.0.1 54321
```

if you stay on the same host. It worked for me at least.